# appendChild not working on divs in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append new div elements to existing divs by using document.getElementsByTagName("div"), converting it to an array, then using appendChild on it. However, when I inspect the frame source of this jsfiddle, it doesn't seem to append it to the divs. It is just:

```
<body>
  <div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of the expected result:

```
<body>
  <div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  </div><div></div>
</div><div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ng58e87w/

```
var allDivs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));  
for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");   
  allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
  console.log(allDivs[i]);
}
```

Comment: `<div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  <div></div></div>
<div></div></div>` Is the output I'm getting, is this not intended?

Comment: how did you get that result? when I am in the jsfiddle and inspect the output frame, i only get <body>
  <div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  </div>
</div>

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as @KyleBecker, which is what I'd expect to see.

Comment: .appendchild appends the element as a child of the element it is called on (inside of its tags). This does NOT mean append as in place the tag after the tag it was called on..appendchild() does `<div><childdiv></childdiv></div>` it does NOT do `<div></div><childdiv></childdiv>`

Comment: @André Dion are you in the same jsfiddle? When I inspect the lower right frame after clicking Run, I still dont see it

Comment: Umm, we're assuming you see the output in your console. Are you?

Comment: I think this is a problem with using View frame source instead of Inspect in Chrome.. Thank you all!

Comment: Inspect the source to know what the source looks like. Use the dev tools html/elements to inspect the results. The problem is not with Chrome.. it's with the user ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, but I believe you are just creating empty divs and adding nothing to them. They show up created when you inspect element in the jsfiddle. I also set their text to something and it seemed to work.

```
var allDivs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));  
  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    newDiv.innerHTML = "Hidden Div?";
    allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log(allDivs[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Ok, now I think this is an issue with Chrome? When I inspect, I can see the new divs, but when I right click on the lower right corner and click View frame source, i only get <body>
  <div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  </div>
</div>

Comment: This is still not a "correct" answer according to the question. The code produces `<body>
  <div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
<div></div>
  </div>
<div></div>
</div>` instead of `<body>
  <div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  </div><div></div>
</div><div></div>` as the question asks for.

Comment: I think the frame source is the same as page source, ie what it looks like BEFORE javascript changes it..

Comment: Is this not the intended purpose Ken? I thought they were trying to add a div into each of the existing divs. That is exactly what happened. A div element was created inside of each div.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.after()` instead of `.appendChild()`.

```js
var words = ['apple','banana','cake'];
console.log(words[0]);
object1 = {
    name:'frank',
    greet:function(){
        alert('hello '+this.name)
    }
};

object2 = {
    name:'andy'
};

// Note that object2 has no greet method.
// But we may "borrow" from object1:

object1.greet.call(object2);
/*
var divs = [];
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName("div") );
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   //do something to each div like
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   arr[i].appendChild(div);
}
*/

var allDivs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));  
  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");   
    allDivs[i].after(newDiv);
    console.log(allDivs[i]);
  }
```

```html
<div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```